# Remove Gapps from cyanogenmod 11

Tags: uninstallation, google-apps

people

I just installed Cyanogenmod from the installer on my Samsung galaxy s4 and it came with Google-apps Pre-installed.
Now i'm not a big fan of Google so i want to get rid of Google-apps how can i do this i know i can flash free-cyan this removes Google analysis and stuff but does not remove Google-apps can someone please tell me how i can remove them.
I got root so hopefully someone can help me.

Greetings,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

The apk files for each are in /system/app (all your installed "system" apps and their odex files, if they're not deodexed, are there). You can rename them, move them, freeze them with the right software, or just delete them.

Also data/data probably has a matching directory with the trash files from those apks (xml, cache, etc) that you can toss.

Note: I've noticed more utilities "uninstall" system apps (does all of this for you if you're rooted): SD Maid, Titanium Backup are two I know of off the top of my head that have added the "uninstall" features since I bought them years ago. That might be your best bet: see if you already have a root tool that does this for you!